# i have run time error any body can check the function and what is missing

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I created a function to check a table.

If the student exists, return Y.

I have a runtime error.

```
create or replace FUNCTION ssc_f_get_speical_need (P_STUDENT_NO IN NUMBER )
 RETURN char
 IS
 l_exist number ;
begin 


select s.STUDENT_NO  
into l_exist 
from SSC_WITH_SPECIAL_NEED  s
where s.STUDENT_NO = P_STUDENT_NO ;

if (l_exist = P_STUDENT_NO) then
return 'Y'  ;
else 
return 'N' ;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: What concrete error do you have?

Comment: A working test case and the exact error stack would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As STUDENT_ID is most probably a primary key column, it won't allow duplicates so the `SELECT` can't return `TOO_MANY_ROWS`. It might, on the other hand, return `NO_DATA_FOUND` if parameter P_STUDENT_ID contains value that doesn't exist in the table.

A simple way to fix it is to use an aggregate function (such as `MAX`, in my example) which will return

- a value if it exists
- NULL if it doesn't
- but won't return `NO_DATA_FOUND` so you don't have to code the exception handler

For testing purposes, I created a *dummy* table based on Scott's EMP table.

```
create table ssc_with_special_need as
  select empno student_no from emp
  where rownum < 5;
```

Now, a function:

```
create or replace function ssc_f_get_special_need
  (p_student_no in number)
  return char
is
  l_exist ssc_with_special_need.student_no%type;
begin
  select max(s.student_no)
    into l_exist
    from ssc_with_special_need s
    where s.student_no = p_student_no;

  return case when l_exist is not null then 'Y'
              else 'N'
         end;
end;
/
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from ssc_with_special_need;

STUDENT_NO
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566

SQL> select ssc_f_get_special_need(1)    result_1, --> doesn't exist in the table (return N)
  2         ssc_f_get_special_need(7369) result_2  --> exists in the table (return Y)
  3  from dual;

RESULT_1   RESULT_2
---------- ----------
N          Y

SQL>
```

A better (proper) way is to handle possible exceptions; as I said, I won't handle `TOO_MANY_ROWS` as it shouldn't ever be raised if the STUDENT_ID is a primary key column.

```
create or replace function ssc_f_get_special_need
  (p_student_no in number)
  return char
is
  l_exist ssc_with_special_need.student_no%type;
begin
  select s.student_no
    into l_exist
    from ssc_with_special_need s
    where s.student_no = p_student_no;
  -- if the above SELECT returned a value, return 'Y' immediately    
  return 'Y';
exception
  when no_data_found then
    -- SELECT didn't find a value and raised an exception - return 'N'
    return 'N';
end;
/
```

Testing: the result is just the same:

```
SQL> select ssc_f_get_special_need(1)    result_1,
  2         ssc_f_get_special_need(7369) result_2
  3  from dual;

RESULT_1   RESULT_2
---------- ----------
N          Y

SQL>
```

I wouldn't use `WHEN OTHERS` as it is, generally speaking, a bad habit: handle what you expect, let Oracle raise everything else (and handle it later, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exceptions then you can re-write your query to something similar to:

```
select decode(count(s.STUDENT_NO),0,'N','Y')
into l_result 
from SSC_WITH_SPECIAL_NEED  s
where s.STUDENT_NO = P_STUDENT_NO ;
```

So, your function will looks like:

```
create or replace function ssc_f_get_speical_need(p_student_no in number )
  return char
is
  l_result varchar2(1) ;
begin
  select decode(count(s.student_no),0,'N','Y')
  into l_result 
  from ssc_with_special_need  s
  where s.student_no = p_student_no ;

  return l_result;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probally you get an error like "no data found" in case there is no Student with the given Student number. 
Try to check your tabel if there is atleast one matching row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssc_f_get_speical_need (p_student_no IN NUMBER)
    RETURN CHAR
IS
    l_exist   NUMBER;
    l_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT   COUNT ( * )
      INTO   l_count
      FROM   ssc_with_special_need s
     WHERE   s.student_no = p_student_no;

    IF l_count > 0
    THEN
        SELECT   s.student_no
          INTO   l_exist
          FROM   ssc_with_special_need s
         WHERE   s.student_no = p_student_no;

        IF l_exist = p_student_no
        THEN
            RETURN 'Y';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN 'N';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception in your function, just to test, if the error persists so the problem is in another where.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION....

BEGIN....

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN --catch any error
RETURN 'E';

END
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/when_others.php

Answer (score 0):

Testing for existence, regardless of using primary key or not, I've always followed Tom Kyte's pattern for selecting from dual where exists.

```
create or replace function ssc_f_get_special_need
  (p_student_no in number)
  return char
is
  l_exist pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into l_exist
  from dual
  where exists
    (select s.student_no
     from ssc_with_special_need s
     where s.student_no = p_student_no);

  return case when l_exist = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end;
end;
/
```